# programmatic/CLI way to tell MSSQL differential backups from full backups?

Tags: sql-server, smo, sqlcmd

Is there an easy way to tell full and differential backups apart just by the metadata present in the .bak file? I've been playing around with osql/sqlcmd and a command like this as a test:

`sqlcmd -Q "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\some_path\some_backup.bak'"`

runs, but DifferentialBaseLSN and DifferentialBaseGUID info is present for the data files in BOTH types of backups =(. Each backup has only three files, an .mdf, an .ndf, and an .ldf. I was hoping to see null or zero values for these attributes for the full database backup, but instead the mdf and ndf files have entries for both of those fields.

Am I out of luck, or is there some other way to dig into the backup file and tell if it is full or differential? Maybe things are easier from something like sql server management objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RESTORE HEADERONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) and the `BackupType` column

The *database file type* is orthogonal to the *backup type*

Comment: +1 for dropping "orthogonal"... had to check the 'ol thesaurus on that one.

Comment: BackupType 1 is full, and BackupType 5 is differential. Perfect! Thank you!